# Sketch complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I want to sketch $\left |z-i \right |+\left | z+i \right |=3$ in the complex plane.
\begin{align*}
\left |x+iy -i\right |+ \left |x+iy+i\right | =3\\
\left |x+i(y-1 \right |+ \left |x+i(y+1)\right | =3\\
\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2}=3\\
(\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}+\sqrt{x^2+(y+1)^2})^2=9
\end{align*}
What should I do here, should I expand the left side?

Comment: Think geometrically, that is an ellipse with foci $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: You already have it: the locus of all points the sum of whose distants from two fixed points is a constant is an...

Comment: What to do depends on what you need to recognise the equation of the geometrical shape. I find the starting point much easier to deal with in that regard, as it says that the sum of the distance from two points is constant.

Comment: @user202729 How did you find the foci $i$ and $-i$? Shouldn't it be $z_1=3+i$ and $z_2=3-i$?

Comment: As defined, all points on ellipse has sum of distances to two foci is constant for a foci. $|z-i|$ is the distance from $z$ to $i$, and $|z+i|$ is the distance from $z$ to $-i$. Their sum is equal to constant $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write the whole equation out, for this can be done in an easier way: you want the locus of points such that the sum-distance to the points $i$ and $-i$ is 3. In other words, this is an *ellipse* centred on the origin with semi-major axis $\frac32$, aligned parallel to the $y$-axis, and semi-minor axis $\frac{\sqrt5}2$. The equation of the ellipse follows as
$$\frac{4x^2}5+\frac{4y^2}9=1.$$

Comment: Great! How did you calculate the axes?

Comment: $i$ and $-i$ are the two foci, and our sum-length is 3. It is well-known that the semi-major axis is half the sum-length, or 3/2; the semi-minor axis can be found by considering the right-angled triangle with hypotenuse 3/2 (half the sum-length) and one leg 1 (half distance between foci).